# Aligning gcc compilation output file to a specific size

Tags: gcc, compilation, linker

for a very specific and not relevant reason, I need to compile a `gcc` file, in a way that it will have a certain file size alignment.

For example, I'm compiling a file, and it has a size of 72148 bytes. However I need it to be aligned to 36 bytes - so the desired size should be 72180 or any other multiple of 36.

Any ideas on how can I achieve that?

Comment: Can't you add a post-build step that adds the padding needed?

Comment: So this is my question, what are those steps? I want it to be part of the compilation because adding manually I got some issues with `SHT` table or other problems..